# Elasticsearch returns documents with a query must_not exists

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch: 6.5.4

Issue: I'm executing a bool query (sample to follow) where I'm checking for the existence of a specific field. The issue is, I'm getting results back where the field does exist but has an empty array.

My question is, how do I properly execute a query and only get results where nlp is not added to the document at all.

Sample query:

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "sort": [{
        "publishedAt": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }],
    "_source": {
        "includes": ["nlp"]
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "nlp.categories.gcp"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Mapping:
(This was automatically created by Elastic Search, with the exception of the null_value, I tried adding that).

```
{
    "mapping": {
        "article": {
            "properties": {
                "nlp": {
                    "properties": {
                        "categories": {
                            "properties": {
                                "gcp": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "confidence": {
                                            "type": "float"
                                        },
                                        "name": {
                                            "type": "text",
                                            "fields": {
                                                "keyword": {
                                                    "type": "keyword",
                                                    "null_value": "[]",
                                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Result:

```
{
    "took": 68,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1126581,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "news",
                "_type": "article",
                "_id": "UTuVmmsBE1H01hY9Rn6i",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "nlp": {
                        "categories": {
                            "gcp": []
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sort": [
                    1509940860000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "news",
                "_type": "article",
                "_id": "2w6PmmsBIpi-jAhhO13F",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "nlp": {
                        "categories": {
                            "gcp": []
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sort": [
                    1510027260000
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When the nlp.categories.gcp has values in it, a typical response would look like this.

```
{
    "took": 26,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 475690,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "news",
                "_type": "article",
                "_id": "6Q6JmmsBIpi-jAhhAlcm",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "nlp": {
                        "categories": {
                            "gcp": [
                                {
                                    "confidence": 0.8999999761581421,
                                    "name": "/Travel/Hotels & Accommodations"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sort": [
                    1510215565000
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "news",
                "_type": "article",
                "_id": "rzunmmsBE1H01hY9sLyE",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "nlp": {
                        "categories": {
                            "gcp": [
                                {
                                    "confidence": 0.9399999976158142,
                                    "name": "/Travel/Hotels & Accommodations"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sort": [
                    1510228881000
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: That mapping looks like a nightmare.  This looks to be an issue with not properly nesting documents (and even with nesting, I doubt nesting that far is performant)

Comment: So, your thoughts are rather then nesting the fields, go to something like nlp_categories_gcp ?

Comment: i am not sure about nesting this one if you don't need them. looks like when indexing your documents you are indexing empty one with empty arrays `[]`. If you index them with 'null' they won't show up in response. can you share how are you indexing your documents with no values.

Comment: either way elastic is returning you correct result, you just don't want that field in output source.

Comment: @user3775217 I think I'm tracking. To sum up what I'm doing, I have a million records that need to be processed, the ones that have never been processed, do not have nlp.categories.gcp at all. The ones with an empty array just mean that when it was processed, no categories were found. So in my mind, items with an empty array, technically should not be showing up in my query.